# using jersey-json to map field names with spaces

Tags: java, json, jersey, mapping

**I have a gson generated POST application/json request like this to work with:**

```
{"Process Name": "Urlaubsantrag", "Action Performed EmailId": "somebody@somewhere.de", "Process Step": "Start"}
```

I want to use jersey to map json data to my bean. Like

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createVacation(Vacation aVacation) 
{
    //DO something
}
```

Where the class Vacation represents my model

```
    public class Vacation {
    String processName;
    String actionPerformedEmailID;
    String processStep;
    String actionName;
etc...
```

Problem is, that all field names in the json code have white spaces in them. I have problems finding correct field names in my model so "process name" will map to processName.

How would I do this? Or is there an other approach to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late to answer this question, but today I faced the same problem (except it was underscore instead of space in a field name). I fixed this using XML binding annotations.

So, we need to annotate the Vacation class and its fields in this way

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Vacation {
@XmlElement(name = "Process Name")
String name;
@XmlElement(name = "Action Performed EmailId")
String actionPerformedEmailID;
@XmlElement(name = "Process Step")
String processStep;
String actionName;
```

etc.

You can omit @XmlElement annotation, if the names of the JSON field and the POJO field are equal.

Comment: This is an alternate but what if there are multiple fields with spaces? I am using  
            @JsonProperty("account id")
            private String accountId; for this but didn't succeed.